# how to give URL navigate id values in charts using vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

how to give URL navigate id values in charts using vb.net

On-clicking the column in the chart its redirecting to another page. But i want to pass the parameter value. how can i do. help me out in this.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="291px" Width="368px" >
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" Url="abc.aspx">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your parameter value like this.

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" Url="abc.aspx?parameterValue=1">
</asp:Series>
```

And in abc page you can get this value via `Request.QueryString`.

```
 int id= Request.QueryString("parameterValue");
```

Comment: actually the code above is not working properly. can u elaborate it Mr.Shree plz.

Comment: it is taking id value as 1 only. not which we are selecting. id is passing id value as 1 only.

Comment: can u send me a example with source code. its urgent.

Comment: Nop you put your value dinamic.I just put 1 for sample.

Comment: if the value should be based on the id from database which we are clicking then  what we should put. i.e lets consider a example. if there are 3 states in the chart A,B and C. if we click on A in the chart it should retrieve all its related data in another chart. plz help me out

Comment: <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="dist_cd" DataTextField="dist_nm" HeaderText="District Name" 
                       DataNavigateUrlFormatString="abc.aspx?dist_cd={0}"> how to use this type in charts??

Comment: i just want my program to execute as given in below example http://techbrij.com/drill-down-asp-net-chart-control

Comment: Finally got the solution.

Comment: Public Sub UpdateAttrib()
        For Each series As Series In Chart1.Series
            For pointIndex As Integer = 0 To series.Points.Count - 1
                Dim toolTip As String = ""
                series.Points(pointIndex).Url = "abc.aspx?region=" + series.Points(pointIndex).AxisLabel
            Next
        Next
    End Sub                       write the above code in .cs file and call below code in next page                                                      If Me.Page.Request("region") IsNot Nothing Then
            region = DirectCast(Me.Page.Request("region"), String)
 End If

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub UpdateAttrib()
        For Each series As Series In Chart1.Series
            For pointIndex As Integer = 0 To series.Points.Count - 1
                Dim toolTip As String = ""
                series.Points(pointIndex).Url = "abc.aspx?region="+ series.Points(pointIndex).AxisLabel
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

write the above code in .cs file and call below code in next page

If Me.Page.Request("region") IsNot Nothing Then
              region = DirectCast(Me.Page.Request("region"), String)
 End If